# Django Filtering Specific QuerySet.values()

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Let's say I have a model Class `Parent` and a Class `Child`. And child has a field called `status` and a `ForeignKey` relationship to `Parent`.

Let's say I retrieve one parent by calling filter (so as to have a QuerySet) by calling `p = Parent.objects.filter(pk=1)`

Now if I call `p.values('children__name')` I will receive a list of dictionaries of the children names to that parent.

My question is, if I wanted to call `p.values('children__name')` but limit the values only if the `status` of the child was specific, how would I do that?

I also want to make sure the original QuerySet is unaltered, as I don't want to filter it down (for larger QuerySets). I just want to filter the values that are based on some parameter.

Is there any way to do this in Django?

Answer (score 11):

You would just filter:

```
p.filter(children__status='whatever').values('children__name')
```

Comment: I do not wish to alter the original QuerySet (which this does). So for example, if I want to list all the parents and children that have a status of 'SICK' then I cannot just do what you did because it would filter down the parents to that. I wish to still keep all the parents, just have the value of 'children__name' be filtered down to those with a specific status. Does that make sense?

Comment: This gets Parents who have any children with a status 'whatever' and then gets all the children names of these parents. That gets you children of other statuses as well, if they had a "sibling" with the status 'whatever'

Comment: works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

You can filter child values on M2M relationships using `Prefetch`. Prefetch specifies how to get data from the through table between Parent and Child and `prefetch_related` triggers the actual query.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

pf = Prefetch('children', Child.objects.filter(status='SICK')
parents = Parent.objects.filter(pk=1).prefetch_related(pf)

sick_children_names = []
for parent in parents:
    sick_children_names.append([child.name for child in parent.children.all()])
```

Alternative approach would be to use the through table itself.

```
names = Parent.children.through.objects.filter(parent_id=1, child__status='SICK').values('children__name')
```

Or with an existing qs p:

```
names = Parent.children.through.objects.filter(parent_id__in=p, child_status='SICK').values('children__name')
```

More on M2M throughs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)